# Are there any guarantees about the splitting order of str.split()?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

According to [the Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), using `str.split()` with `maxsplit` specified will split a string up to `maxsplit` times.

However, it never explicitly specifies that these splits will be executed left to right. There is a related function [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) that guarantees right to left split ordering.

Aside from doing string reverse followed by `str.rsplit()`, is there any way to guarantee a left to right splitting order? Are there any situations where `str.split()` will NOT use a left to right order?

Comment: `str.split` always splits left-to-right, `.rsplit` the other way.

Comment: This is never specified in the docs. Where are you getting your guarantee? I understand that empirically, this is the result, but observations are not guarantees.

Comment: @ConnorBlanck -- If you'd like, you're free to look at the implementation.  ltr splitting is the intention of the method -- `maxsplit` would be of virtually no use if you couldn't tell _where_ the splits would occur.  I'm guessing that the docs writers just found it too obvious to mention.  If you feel like this is necessary in the documentation, feel free to submit a bug against the docs.

Comment: No, it is not explicitly specified. However, it is implicitly very clear and any implementation that did anything else would break a whole lot of code and fail basic language test suites. Not to mention that to implement it any other way would be ludicrous - randomly? Middle out? Alternating start and end? What has led you to the fear that it would do anything *other* than LtR?

Comment: @mgilson I think nothing should be "too obvious to mention" in the documentation for an important string method. For instance, `str.split()` could be implemented with binary search to locate the delimiters.

Comment: Binary search is perfect for speeding up searches on ordered sequences, but makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Binary search would find *a* delimiter quickly; it would not be any faster than a linear scan for finding *all* delimiters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think there are some unspoken assumptions being made about how a split method _should_ work rather than how it's _guaranteed_ to work. I found it strange that `str.rsplit()` explicitly says it uses the rightmost splits, but `str.split()` makes no such comment.

Comment: @chepner When you use the `maxsplit` argument, splitting stops after `maxsplit` delimiters have been encountered, while this may be _all_ delimiters, this is not certain.

Comment: Yes, there are unspoken (err, unwritten?) assumptions, I guess because that's how it's always been done and the thought of doing it differently seems, frankly, ludicrous. Strictly, the docs only guarantee that with `maxsplit` you will get at most `maxsplit + 1` chunks of text, broken apart on `maxsplit` delimiters, rather than that they will be the *first* `maxsplit` delimiters. @mgilson is right, if you think this needs to be explicitly guaranteed you should submit a bug or patch against the documentation, but in context it doesn't seem unclear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- Definitely not unclear to me since there is an `rsplit` method which guarantees right to left splitting ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for guarantees that splitting with the `maxsplit` argument splits from left-to-right, you only need to look at the builtin [python test suite](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/test/string_tests.py#l359).

Here's an excerpt:

```
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal(['a|b|c|d'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 0)
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b|c|d'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 1)
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b', 'c|d'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 2)
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 3)
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 4)
    self.checkequal(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|',
                    sys.maxsize-2)
    self.checkequal(['a|b|c|d'], 'a|b|c|d', 'split', '|', 0)
    self.checkequal(['a', '', 'b||c||d'], 'a||b||c||d', 'split', '|', 2)
    self.checkequal(['abcd'], 'abcd', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal([''], '', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal(['endcase ', ''], 'endcase |', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal(['', ' startcase'], '| startcase', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal(['', 'bothcase', ''], '|bothcase|', 'split', '|')
    self.checkequal(['a', '', 'b\x00c\x00d'], 'a\x00\x00b\x00c\x00d', 'split', '\x00', 2)
```

From the tests, it is clear that any implementation that did something different would fail these tests.

Comment: This is a pretty good guarantee. I'll see about getting the docs to specify this assumption. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

CPython is considered to be the reference implementation of Python. According to CPython source code `str.split` is guaranteed to split in left-to-right order. You can look up how `str.split` is implemented, here is a link http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Objects/stringlib/split.h?view=markup

For example, in `stringlib_split_char` (as well as in `stringlib_split_whitespace`, which are both used in `stringlib_split` (`str.split`)) one can clearly see that the string is processed from left to right (`i` and `j` are used to index the string, they both start with zero and are being incremented, `maxsplit` does not affect how indexes are treated, `maxsplit` only provides early exit from the loop):

```
Py_LOCAL_INLINE(PyObject *)
stringlib_split_char(PyObject* str_obj,
                     const STRINGLIB_CHAR* str, Py_ssize_t str_len,
                     const STRINGLIB_CHAR ch,
                     Py_ssize_t maxcount)
{
    // ... some code omitted

    i = j = 0;
    while ((j < str_len) && (maxcount-- > 0)) {
        for(; j < str_len; j++) {
            /* I found that using memchr makes no difference */
            if (str[j] == ch) {
                SPLIT_ADD(str, i, j);
                i = j = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // ... some code omitted
```

And in `stringlib_rsplit_char` (used in `str.rsplit`) both `i` and `j` indexes start at the end of string and being decremented:

```
i = j = str_len - 1;
while ((i >= 0) && (maxcount-- > 0)) {
    for(; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == ch) {
            SPLIT_ADD(str, i + 1, j + 1);
            j = i = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that *"how [it] is implemented"* is **not** the same as whether or not that is guaranteed for any given implementation.

Comment: cpython is considered to be a reference implementation of python language

Comment: *Considered*, yes. You could put that in the answer, and note that it should be *the* not *a* reference!