# does .split() always preserve the order of elements from the string?

Tags: python

I was wondering if the order of elements in my string with comma seperated elements is always preserved if I use the .split() functionality or is there a chance that elements might turn up in different order in the list? I dont think so but I cant tell for sure either. maybe someone can answer that question for sure.

example:

```
s = "cat,dog,dolphin,zebra,ape"
l = s.split(",")
typically would turn to -> l = ["cat","dog","dolphin","zebra","ape"]
```

might it happend l turns out to be ["ape","cat"...] with elements in different order after using split(",") ?

Thanks for the clarification.
Best

Comment: it does preserve the order.

Comment: yes always, split creates a list

Comment: Where can we look for the implementation of functions in python? Is there a github repo?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148952/are-there-any-guarantees-about-the-splitting-order-of-str-split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `.split()` always preserves the order of the characters in the string.

Think of it this way. Your string is like a rectangular slice of pizza with stripes on it. All `.split()` does is cut along those stripes (the argument you supply / the " " character). The order of the string is preserved; it never changes.

In your case, `"cat,dog,dolphin,zebra,ape".split()` would **always** `return` `["cat", "dog", "dolphin", "zebra", "ape"]`.

For more information, [see the docs on `.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

A short answer for a short question:

Yes, it does.

See the [docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> "For example, ' 1  2   3  '.split() returns ['1', '2', '3']"